# Submit button won't ReRender my VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, class, rerender, button

I am in the final stages of creating this awesome custom VF report.  Everything is coming together but now the Output Panel won't refresh. I have it setup so an end user can select a date range and then click the Submit button to refresh the information shown in the report.  It was working until I recently made some changes to make my report work.  It appears that the submit button is working but there is no data to be shown so it does not refresh.  I am wondering if the 2 private classes that I am calling are not refreshing with the submit button.  Any help would be great. Below is the code to my VF Page, Apex Class, and 1 of my VF Components.  Thanks.

APEX CLASS:

```
public class MonthlySeizureController1{
    public task taskRec                 { get; set; }
    public task taskRec1                { get; set; }
    public List<Case__c> theCases              { get; set; } // this was the ca reference
    public Map<Id, Business__c> businessMap   { get; set; } // this was the bus1 reference
    public MonthlySeizureController1(ApexPages.StandardController sc){
        taskRec = new task (ActivityDate__c = Date.today().addMonths(-3));
        taskRec1 = new task (ActivityDate__c = Date.today());
        // get the supply chain chases in the last month be careful of 10k cases in this result
        this.theCases = querySupplyChainCasesBetweenDates(taskRec.ActivityDate__c, taskRec1.ActivityDate__c);
        // collect the ids of the businesses in these cases
        Set<Id> businessIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (Case__c c : theCases) {
            for (BusinessCasesAssociation__c bca : c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r) {
                businessIds.add(bca.Business__c); 
            }
        } 
        // get the businesses related to these cases and assign them to the variable in the controller
        this.businessMap = queryBusinesses(businessIDs);
    }
    public MonthlySeizureController1() {      
    }  
    private Map<Id, Business__c> queryBusinesses(Set<Id> businessIDs) { 
        Map<Id, Business__c> result =  new Map<Id, Business__c>([SELECT Id
                                                                    , Name
                                                                    , Business_Name__c
                                                                    , Business_Type__c
                                                                    , (SELECT Street__c
                                                                            , Business_City__c
                                                                            , State_Province__c
                                                                            , Country__c
                                                                            , Zip_Postal_Code__c 
                                                                        FROM BPR_Business_Addresses__r)
                                                                    , (SELECT Number_Type__c
                                                                            , Number__c 
                                                                        FROM Business_Phone_Numbers__r)
                                                                    , (SELECT Email_Bus__c 
                                                                        FROM Email_Businesses__r)
                                                                FROM Business__c
                                                                WHERE (Id = :businessIDs)]);
        return result;
    }
    private List<Case__c> querySupplyChainCasesBetweenDates(Date lowerDate, Date upperDate) { 
        List<Case__c> cases = [SELECT Id
                                    , Name
                                    , CreatedDate
                                    , LastModifiedDate
                                    , Owner.FirstName
                                    , Owner.LastName
                                    , Notification_Date__c
                                    , Incident_City__c
                                    , Incident_Country__r.Name
                                    , Total_Product__c
                                    , Comments_Postal_Express__c
                                    , (SELECT RecordType.Name
                                            , Container__c
                                            , Ship_Date__c
                                            , Date_of_Retention__c
                                            , Carrier__c
                                            , Port_of_Loading__c
                                            , Port_of_Discharge__c
                                            , Container_Type__c
                                            , Place_of_Retention__c
                                            , Vessel__c
                                            , Master_BOL__c
                                            , House_BOL__c
                                        FROM Incident_Locations__r)
                                    , (SELECT Brand__c
                                            , Product_Detail__c
                                            , Product_Types__c
                                            , Total_Product_Quantity__c 
                                        FROM Products__r)
                                    , (SELECT Business__c
                                            , Case__c
                                            , Business__r.Business_Name__c
                                            , Business__r.Business_Type__c 
                                        FROM BusinessCasesAssociations__r)
                                    , (SELECT Subject_Name__r.Subject_Name__c
                                            , Subject_Name__r.Subject_Type__c 
                                        FROM Subject_for_Cases__r)
                                FROM Case__c
                                WHERE Supply_Chain_Type__c = 'SEA'
                                    AND Notification_Date__c >= :lowerDate
                                    AND Notification_Date__c <= :upperDate
                                ORDER BY Notification_Date__c ASC];
        return cases;
    }
    public PageReference next(){
        PageReference nextpage = new PageReference('/apex/securityreport1ppv');
        return nextpage;
    }
    public PageReference next1(){
        PageReference nextpage = new PageReference('/apex/securityreport1sap');
        return nextpage;
    }
}
```

VF PAGE:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case__c" extensions="MonthlySeizureController1">
<style type="text/css">
    table.myTable{
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table.myTable td{
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    table.myTable th{
        border: 2px solid black;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    a.linkAsBtn,
    a.linkAsBtn:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 3px 6px;
    }
</style>
<apex:form id="refreshForm">
<apex:panelGrid columns="8" id="dates1">
    <b>Start Date: </b><apex:inputfield value="{!taskRec.ActivityDate__c}" required="true"/>
    <b>End Date: </b><apex:inputfield value="{!taskRec1.ActivityDate__c}" required="true"/>
    &nbsp;<apex:commandLink value="Submit" rerender="refresh"  styleClass="btn linkAsBtn"/>  
    <apex:commandLink value="Printable View" action="{!next}" id="cmdNext" target="_blank" styleClass="btn linkAsBtn"/> 
    <apex:commandLink value="Save as PDF" action="{!next1}" id="cmdNext1" target="_blank" styleClass="btn linkAsBtn"/>
</apex:panelGrid>
<apex:outputPanel id="refresh">  
    <table class="myTable">
        <tr>
            <th>BPR Case</th>
            <th>BP MGR</th>
            <th>SHIPPING DATE/SEIZURE DATE</th>
            <th>NOTIFY DATE</th>
            <th>SEIZURE LOCATION</th>
            <th>CONTAINER NO.</th>
            <th>CARRIER</th>
            <th>TRADING CO.</th>
            <th>SHIPPER CO.</th>           
            <th>SHIPPER NAME</th>
            <th>SHIPPER ADDRESS</th>
            <th>SHIPPER PHONE</th>
            <th>SHIPPER EMAIL</th>            
            <th>PORT OF LOADING</th>                      
            <th>MANUFACTURER/PROVIDER</th>
            <th>MANUFACTURER/PROVIDER ADDRESS</th>            
            <th>CONSIGNEE BUSINESS</th>
            <th>CONSIGNEE NAME</th>
            <th>CONSIGNEE ADDRESS</th> 
            <th>CONSIGNEE PHONE</th>
            <th>CONSIGNEE EMAIL</th>           
            <th>PORT OF DISCHARGE</th>            
            <th>NOTIFY PARTY</th>
            <th>NOTIFY PARTY ADDRESS</th> 
            <th>NOTIFY PARTY PHONE</th>            
            <th>PRODUCT</th>
            <th>AMOUNT (pairs, items)</th>
            <th>CONTAINER STATS</th>
            <th>ADDITIONAL INFORMATION</th>
        </tr>
    <apex:repeat value="{!theCases}" var="c">
        <tr>
            <td>
            <a href="https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/{!c.Id}">{!c.name}</a>
            </td>
            <td>
            <apex:outputText value="{!c.Owner.FirstName}"></apex:outputText>&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{!c.Owner.LastName}"></apex:outputText>
            </td>
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.Incident_Locations__r}" var="loc">
                <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'-'dd'-'yyyy}"><apex:param value="{!loc.Ship_Date__c}"/></apex:outputText>/&nbsp;
                <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'-'dd'-'yyyy}"><apex:param value="{!loc.Date_of_Retention__c}"/></apex:outputText><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>
            <td>
            <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'-'dd'-'yyyy}"><apex:param value="{!c.Notification_Date__c}"/></apex:outputText>
            </td>
            <td>
            <apex:outputText value="{!c.Incident_City__c}"></apex:outputText>/&nbsp;
            <apex:outputText value="{!c.Incident_Country__r.Name}"></apex:outputText>
            </td>
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.Incident_Locations__r}" var="loc">
                <apex:outputText value="{!loc.Container__c}"></apex:outputText><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.Incident_Locations__r}" var="loc">
                <apex:outputText value="{!loc.Carrier__c}"></apex:outputText><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="bus">
                <apex:outputText value="{!bus.Business__r.Business_Name__c}" rendered="{!bus.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Trading Company'}"></apex:outputText><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>   
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="bus">
                <apex:outputText value="{!bus.Business__r.Business_Name__c}" rendered="{!bus.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Exporter'}"></apex:outputText>
            </apex:repeat>  
            </td>                                  
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.Subject_for_Cases__r}" var="sub">
                <apex:outputText value="{!sub.Subject_Name__r.Subject_Name__c}" rendered="{!sub.Subject_Name__r.Subject_Type__c = 'Exporter'}"></apex:outputText><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="businessCaseAssociation">
                <c:business_shipper_contact_info theBusiness="{!businessMap[businessCaseAssociation.Business__c]}" rendered="{!businessCaseAssociation.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Exporter'}"/><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>   
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="businessCaseAssociation">
                <c:business_shipper_contact_info2 theBusiness="{!businessMap[businessCaseAssociation.Business__c]}" rendered="{!businessCaseAssociation.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Exporter'}"/><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td> 
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="businessCaseAssociation">
                <c:business_shipper_contact_info3 theBusiness="{!businessMap[businessCaseAssociation.Business__c]}" rendered="{!businessCaseAssociation.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Exporter'}"/><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>                         
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.Incident_Locations__r}" var="loc">
                <apex:outputText value="{!loc.Port_of_Loading__c}"></apex:outputText><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>                                              
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="bus">
                <apex:outputText value="{!bus.Business__r.Business_Name__c}" rendered="{!bus.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Factory/Manufacturer'}"></apex:outputText><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="businessCaseAssociation">
                <c:business_shipper_contact_info theBusiness="{!businessMap[businessCaseAssociation.Business__c]}" rendered="{!businessCaseAssociation.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Factory/Manufacturer'}"/><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>             
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="bus">
                <apex:outputText value="{!bus.Business__r.Business_Name__c}" rendered="{!bus.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Importer'}"></apex:outputText><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td> 
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.Subject_for_Cases__r}" var="sub">
                <apex:outputText value="{!sub.Subject_Name__r.Subject_Name__c}" rendered="{!sub.Subject_Name__r.Subject_Type__c = 'Importer'}"></apex:outputText><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td> 
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="businessCaseAssociation">
                <c:business_shipper_contact_info theBusiness="{!businessMap[businessCaseAssociation.Business__c]}" rendered="{!businessCaseAssociation.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Importer'}"/><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="businessCaseAssociation">
                <c:business_shipper_contact_info2 theBusiness="{!businessMap[businessCaseAssociation.Business__c]}" rendered="{!businessCaseAssociation.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Importer'}"/><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="businessCaseAssociation">
                <c:business_shipper_contact_info3 theBusiness="{!businessMap[businessCaseAssociation.Business__c]}" rendered="{!businessCaseAssociation.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Importer'}"/><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>                                    
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.Incident_Locations__r}" var="loc">
                <apex:outputText value="{!loc.Port_of_Discharge__c}"></apex:outputText><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>                                    
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="bus">
                <apex:outputText value="{!bus.Business__r.Business_Name__c}" rendered="{!bus.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Notify Party'}"></apex:outputText><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td> 
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="businessCaseAssociation">
                <c:business_shipper_contact_info theBusiness="{!businessMap[businessCaseAssociation.Business__c]}" rendered="{!businessCaseAssociation.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Notify Party'}"/><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="businessCaseAssociation">
                <c:business_shipper_contact_info2 theBusiness="{!businessMap[businessCaseAssociation.Business__c]}" rendered="{!businessCaseAssociation.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Notify Party'}"/><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>                                                                                                
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.Products__r}" var="pro">
                <apex:outputText value="{!pro.Brand__c}"></apex:outputText>&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{!pro.Product_Types__c}"></apex:outputText>&nbsp;(<apex:outputText value="{0,number,###,###}"><apex:param value="{!pro.Total_Product_Quantity__c}"/></apex:outputText>)<br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>
            <td>
                <apex:outputText value="{!c.Total_Product__c}"></apex:outputText>
            </td>
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.Incident_Locations__r}" var="loc">
                <apex:outputText value="{!loc.Container_Type__c}"></apex:outputText><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>
            <td>
                <apex:outputText value="{!c.Comments_Postal_Express__c}"></apex:outputText>
            </td>            
         </tr>              
    </apex:repeat>
    </table>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

VF COMPONENT:

```
<apex:component >
    <apex:attribute name="theBusiness" type="Business__c" description="The business__c record" required="true" />
        <apex:repeat value="{!theBusiness.BPR_Business_Addresses__r}" var="addr">
            <apex:outputText value="{!addr.Street__c}" />&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{!addr.Business_City__c}" />&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{!addr.State_Province__c}" />&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{!addr.Country__c}" />&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{!addr.Zip_Postal_Code__c}" />     
        </apex:repeat>      
</apex:component>
```

UPDATED APEX CLASS BASED ON crmprogdev PROPOSAL:

```
public class MonthlySeizureController1{
    public task taskRec                 { get; set; }
    public task taskRec1                { get; set; }
    public List<Case__c> theCases              { get; set; } // this was the ca reference
    public Map<Id, Business__c> businessMap   { get; set; } // this was the bus1 reference
    public MonthlySeizureController1(ApexPages.StandardController sc){
        this();
    }
    public MonthlySeizureController1() {  
        taskRec = new task (ActivityDate__c = Date.today().addMonths(-3));
        taskRec1 = new task (ActivityDate__c = Date.today());
        // get the supply chain chases in the last month be careful of 10k cases in this result
        this.theCases = querySupplyChainCasesBetweenDates(taskRec.ActivityDate__c, taskRec1.ActivityDate__c);
        // collect the ids of the businesses in these cases
        Set<Id> businessIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (Case__c c : theCases) {
            for (BusinessCasesAssociation__c bca : c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r) {
                businessIds.add(bca.Business__c); 
            }
        } 
        // get the businesses related to these cases and assign them to the variable in the controller
        this.businessMap = queryBusinesses(businessIDs); 
    }  
    public void refresh() {
        taskRec = new task (ActivityDate__c = Date.today().addMonths(-3));
        taskRec1 = new task (ActivityDate__c = Date.today());
        // get the supply chain chases in the last month be careful of 10k cases in this result
        this.theCases = querySupplyChainCasesBetweenDates(taskRec.ActivityDate__c, taskRec1.ActivityDate__c);
        // collect the ids of the businesses in these cases
        Set<Id> businessIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (Case__c c : theCases) {
            for (BusinessCasesAssociation__c bca : c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r) {
                businessIds.add(bca.Business__c); 
            }
        } 
        // get the businesses related to these cases and assign them to the variable in the controller
        this.businessMap = queryBusinesses(businessIDs);
    }

    private Map<Id, Business__c> queryBusinesses(Set<Id> businessIDs) { 
        Map<Id, Business__c> result =  new Map<Id, Business__c>([SELECT Id
                                                                    , Name
                                                                    , Business_Name__c
                                                                    , Business_Type__c
                                                                    , (SELECT Street__c
                                                                            , Business_City__c
                                                                            , State_Province__c
                                                                            , Country__c
                                                                            , Zip_Postal_Code__c 
                                                                        FROM BPR_Business_Addresses__r)
                                                                    , (SELECT Number_Type__c
                                                                            , Number__c 
                                                                        FROM Business_Phone_Numbers__r)
                                                                    , (SELECT Email_Bus__c 
                                                                        FROM Email_Businesses__r)
                                                                FROM Business__c
                                                                WHERE (Id = :businessIDs)]);
        return result;
    }
    private List<Case__c> querySupplyChainCasesBetweenDates(Date lowerDate, Date upperDate) { 
        List<Case__c> cases = [SELECT Id
                                    , Name
                                    , CreatedDate
                                    , LastModifiedDate
                                    , Owner.FirstName
                                    , Owner.LastName
                                    , Notification_Date__c
                                    , Incident_City__c
                                    , Incident_Country__r.Name
                                    , Total_Product__c
                                    , Comments_Postal_Express__c
                                    , (SELECT RecordType.Name
                                            , Container__c
                                            , Ship_Date__c
                                            , Date_of_Retention__c
                                            , Carrier__c
                                            , Port_of_Loading__c
                                            , Port_of_Discharge__c
                                            , Container_Type__c
                                            , Place_of_Retention__c
                                            , Vessel__c
                                            , Master_BOL__c
                                            , House_BOL__c
                                        FROM Incident_Locations__r)
                                    , (SELECT Brand__c
                                            , Product_Detail__c
                                            , Product_Types__c
                                            , Total_Product_Quantity__c 
                                        FROM Products__r)
                                    , (SELECT Business__c
                                            , Case__c
                                            , Business__r.Business_Name__c
                                            , Business__r.Business_Type__c 
                                        FROM BusinessCasesAssociations__r)
                                    , (SELECT Subject_Name__r.Subject_Name__c
                                            , Subject_Name__r.Subject_Type__c 
                                        FROM Subject_for_Cases__r)
                                FROM Case__c
                                WHERE Supply_Chain_Type__c = 'SEA'
                                    AND Notification_Date__c >= :lowerDate
                                    AND Notification_Date__c <= :upperDate
                                ORDER BY Notification_Date__c ASC];
        return cases;
    }
    public PageReference next(){
        PageReference nextpage = new PageReference('/apex/securityreport1ppv');
        return nextpage;
    }
    public PageReference next1(){
        PageReference nextpage = new PageReference('/apex/securityreport1sap');
        return nextpage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `save()` method definition ?

Comment: sorry, I was testing and forgot to remove that. I updated it above. thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click on `<apex:commandLink value="Submit" action="{!save}" rerender="refresh"  styleClass="btn linkAsBtn"/>` you're calling the SAVE method from the standard controller, not any of the private methods you mention in your Extension. In fact, you can't call a private method directly. A private method can only be called from within a controller.

Since I don't know what it is that you want to call, I can't give you specific direction on how to revise your code except to say that you need to create a method within your extension that you call from that button and have it rerender your output panel.

**Edit**

Since you don't need to return a new page reference, you can create a method of type `public void` that simply calls `MonthlySeizureController1()` and the two private methods from your command button. If you do need to save at the same time, you could call it DoSave and include your DML at the end of it. Be sure to add Page Messages to it should you have any save errors.

Comment: Appreciate the info.  I am trying to call the MonthlySeizureController1 method but since I had to pull the private methods out to do some calculations they only run onload rather than when I rerender the outputpanel.  I think you are right I need to create a class that calls both the private methods along with the MonthlySeizurecontroller1 so I get the correct data.  I am unsure how to do this so any help would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: See edited answer

Comment: Looks like it is now getting the data which is great but it is not rerendering the output panel.  Any ideas?  I tried wrapping it in a 2nd outputpanel but that didn't work either.  Getting closer.  Thanks.

Comment: Your button should have an Action that call the method and use "onclick".

Comment: Here is what I have `<apex:commandLink value="Submit" action="{!refresh}" onclick="refresh" rerender="refresh"  styleClass="btn linkAsBtn"/> ` Not sure what else to try.

Comment: You've created another inner class, not a method. You may just as well be calling MonthlySeizureController1(), the two private methods will run automatically if it's called. If you want the existing data to persist, then you need make them public so another method can retrieve previous results of their data (if that's what you need). Just call them from your constructor as you do now. You're using `this` keyword in your controller. That's an instance method. You create a new instance each time you call the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code that works great. Thanks for everyone's help.

FINAL APEX CLASS:

```
public class MonthlySeizureController1{
    public task taskRec                 { get; set; }
    public task taskRec1                { get; set; }
    public List<Case__c> theCases              { get; set; } // this was the ca reference
    public Map<Id, Business__c> businessMap   { get; set; } // this was the bus1 reference
    public MonthlySeizureController1(ApexPages.StandardController sc){
        this();
    }
    public MonthlySeizureController1() {  
        taskRec = new task (ActivityDate__c = Date.today().addMonths(-3));
        taskRec1 = new task (ActivityDate__c = Date.today());
        // get the supply chain chases in the last month be careful of 10k cases in this result
        this.theCases = querySupplyChainCasesBetweenDates(taskRec.ActivityDate__c, taskRec1.ActivityDate__c);
        // collect the ids of the businesses in these cases
        Set<Id> businessIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (Case__c c : theCases) {
            for (BusinessCasesAssociation__c bca : c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r) {
                businessIds.add(bca.Business__c); 
            }
        } 
        // get the businesses related to these cases and assign them to the variable in the controller
        this.businessMap = queryBusinesses(businessIDs); 
    }  
    public void refresh() {
        this.theCases = querySupplyChainCasesBetweenDates(taskRec.ActivityDate__c, taskRec1.ActivityDate__c);
        // collect the ids of the businesses in these cases
        Set<Id> businessIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (Case__c c : theCases) {
            for (BusinessCasesAssociation__c bca : c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r) {
                businessIds.add(bca.Business__c); 
            }
        } 
        // get the businesses related to these cases and assign them to the variable in the controller
        this.businessMap = queryBusinesses(businessIDs);
    }

    public Map<Id, Business__c> queryBusinesses(Set<Id> businessIDs) { 
        Map<Id, Business__c> result =  new Map<Id, Business__c>([SELECT Id
                                                                    , Name
                                                                    , Business_Name__c
                                                                    , Business_Type__c
                                                                    , (SELECT Street__c
                                                                            , Business_City__c
                                                                            , State_Province__c
                                                                            , Country__c
                                                                            , Zip_Postal_Code__c 
                                                                        FROM BPR_Business_Addresses__r)
                                                                    , (SELECT Number_Type__c
                                                                            , Number__c 
                                                                        FROM Business_Phone_Numbers__r)
                                                                    , (SELECT Email_Bus__c 
                                                                        FROM Email_Businesses__r)
                                                                FROM Business__c
                                                                WHERE (Id = :businessIDs)]);
        return result;
    }
    public List<Case__c> querySupplyChainCasesBetweenDates(Date lowerDate, Date upperDate) { 
        List<Case__c> cases = [SELECT Id
                                    , Name
                                    , CreatedDate
                                    , LastModifiedDate
                                    , Owner.FirstName
                                    , Owner.LastName
                                    , Notification_Date__c
                                    , Incident_City__c
                                    , Incident_Country__r.Name
                                    , Total_Product__c
                                    , Comments_Postal_Express__c
                                    , (SELECT RecordType.Name
                                            , Container__c
                                            , Ship_Date__c
                                            , Date_of_Retention__c
                                            , Carrier__c
                                            , Port_of_Loading__c
                                            , Port_of_Discharge__c
                                            , Container_Type__c
                                            , Place_of_Retention__c
                                            , Vessel__c
                                            , Master_BOL__c
                                            , House_BOL__c
                                        FROM Incident_Locations__r)
                                    , (SELECT Brand__c
                                            , Product_Detail__c
                                            , Product_Types__c
                                            , Total_Product_Quantity__c 
                                        FROM Products__r)
                                    , (SELECT Business__c
                                            , Case__c
                                            , Business__r.Business_Name__c
                                            , Business__r.Business_Type__c 
                                        FROM BusinessCasesAssociations__r)
                                    , (SELECT Subject_Name__r.Subject_Name__c
                                            , Subject_Name__r.Subject_Type__c 
                                        FROM Subject_for_Cases__r)
                                FROM Case__c
                                WHERE Supply_Chain_Type__c = 'SEA'
                                    AND Notification_Date__c >= :lowerDate
                                    AND Notification_Date__c <= :upperDate
                                ORDER BY Notification_Date__c ASC];
        return cases;
    }
    public PageReference next(){
        PageReference nextpage = new PageReference('/apex/securityreport1ppv');
        return nextpage;
    }
    public PageReference next1(){
        PageReference nextpage = new PageReference('/apex/securityreport1sap');
        return nextpage;
    }
}
```

FINAL VF PAGE:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case__c" extensions="MonthlySeizureController1">
<style type="text/css">
    table.myTable{
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table.myTable td{
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    table.myTable th{
        border: 2px solid black;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    a.linkAsBtn,
    a.linkAsBtn:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 3px 6px;
    }
</style>
<apex:form id="refreshForm">
<apex:panelGrid columns="8" id="dates1">
    <b>Start Date: </b><apex:inputfield value="{!taskRec.ActivityDate__c}" required="true"/>
    <b>End Date: </b><apex:inputfield value="{!taskRec1.ActivityDate__c}" required="true"/>&nbsp;
    <apex:commandLink value="Submit" onclick="update()" rerender="refresh1"  styleClass="btn linkAsBtn" immediate="true"/>  
    <apex:commandLink value="Printable View" action="{!next}" id="cmdNext" target="_blank" styleClass="btn linkAsBtn"/> 
    <apex:commandLink value="Save as PDF" action="{!next1}" id="cmdNext1" target="_blank" styleClass="btn linkAsBtn"/>
    <apex:actionFunction id="update" action="{!refresh}" name="update" >
          <apex:param name="update" assignTo="{!refresh}" value="update"/>
     </apex:actionFunction>    
</apex:panelGrid>
<apex:outputPanel id="refresh1"> 
    <table class="myTable">
        <tr>
            <th>BPR Case</th>
            <th>BP MGR</th>
            <th>SHIPPING DATE/SEIZURE DATE</th>
            <th>NOTIFY DATE</th>
            <th>SEIZURE LOCATION</th>
            <th>CONTAINER NO.</th>
            <th>CARRIER</th>
            <th>TRADING CO.</th>
            <th>SHIPPER CO.</th>           
            <th>SHIPPER NAME</th>
            <th>SHIPPER ADDRESS</th>
            <th>SHIPPER PHONE</th>
            <th>SHIPPER EMAIL</th>            
            <th>PORT OF LOADING</th>                      
            <th>MANUFACTURER/PROVIDER</th>
            <th>MANUFACTURER/PROVIDER ADDRESS</th>            
            <th>CONSIGNEE BUSINESS</th>
            <th>CONSIGNEE NAME</th>
            <th>CONSIGNEE ADDRESS</th> 
            <th>CONSIGNEE PHONE</th>
            <th>CONSIGNEE EMAIL</th>           
            <th>PORT OF DISCHARGE</th>            
            <th>NOTIFY PARTY</th>
            <th>NOTIFY PARTY ADDRESS</th> 
            <th>NOTIFY PARTY PHONE</th>            
            <th>PRODUCT</th>
            <th>AMOUNT (pairs, items)</th>
            <th>CONTAINER STATS</th>
            <th>ADDITIONAL INFORMATION</th>
        </tr>
    <apex:repeat value="{!theCases}" var="c">
        <tr>
            <td>
            <a href="https://nikelegal--bprqa.cs51.my.salesforce.com/{!c.Id}">{!c.name}</a>
            </td>
            <td>
            <apex:outputText value="{!c.Owner.FirstName}"></apex:outputText>&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{!c.Owner.LastName}"></apex:outputText>
            </td>
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.Incident_Locations__r}" var="loc">
                <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'-'dd'-'yyyy}"><apex:param value="{!loc.Ship_Date__c}"/></apex:outputText>/&nbsp;
                <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'-'dd'-'yyyy}"><apex:param value="{!loc.Date_of_Retention__c}"/></apex:outputText><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>
            <td>
            <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'-'dd'-'yyyy}"><apex:param value="{!c.Notification_Date__c}"/></apex:outputText>
            </td>
            <td>
            <apex:outputText value="{!c.Incident_City__c}"></apex:outputText>/&nbsp;
            <apex:outputText value="{!c.Incident_Country__r.Name}"></apex:outputText>
            </td>
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.Incident_Locations__r}" var="loc">
                <apex:outputText value="{!loc.Container__c}"></apex:outputText><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.Incident_Locations__r}" var="loc">
                <apex:outputText value="{!loc.Carrier__c}"></apex:outputText><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="bus">
                <apex:outputText value="{!bus.Business__r.Business_Name__c}" rendered="{!bus.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Trading Company'}"></apex:outputText><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>   
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="bus">
                <apex:outputText value="{!bus.Business__r.Business_Name__c}" rendered="{!bus.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Exporter'}"></apex:outputText>
            </apex:repeat>  
            </td>                                  
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.Subject_for_Cases__r}" var="sub">
                <apex:outputText value="{!sub.Subject_Name__r.Subject_Name__c}" rendered="{!sub.Subject_Name__r.Subject_Type__c = 'Exporter'}"></apex:outputText><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="businessCaseAssociation">
                <c:business_shipper_contact_info theBusiness="{!businessMap[businessCaseAssociation.Business__c]}" rendered="{!businessCaseAssociation.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Exporter'}"/><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>   
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="businessCaseAssociation">
                <c:business_shipper_contact_info2 theBusiness="{!businessMap[businessCaseAssociation.Business__c]}" rendered="{!businessCaseAssociation.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Exporter'}"/><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td> 
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="businessCaseAssociation">
                <c:business_shipper_contact_info3 theBusiness="{!businessMap[businessCaseAssociation.Business__c]}" rendered="{!businessCaseAssociation.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Exporter'}"/><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>                         
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.Incident_Locations__r}" var="loc">
                <apex:outputText value="{!loc.Port_of_Loading__c}"></apex:outputText><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>                                              
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="bus">
                <apex:outputText value="{!bus.Business__r.Business_Name__c}" rendered="{!bus.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Factory/Manufacturer'}"></apex:outputText><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="businessCaseAssociation">
                <c:business_shipper_contact_info theBusiness="{!businessMap[businessCaseAssociation.Business__c]}" rendered="{!businessCaseAssociation.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Factory/Manufacturer'}"/><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>             
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="bus">
                <apex:outputText value="{!bus.Business__r.Business_Name__c}" rendered="{!bus.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Importer'}"></apex:outputText><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td> 
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.Subject_for_Cases__r}" var="sub">
                <apex:outputText value="{!sub.Subject_Name__r.Subject_Name__c}" rendered="{!sub.Subject_Name__r.Subject_Type__c = 'Importer'}"></apex:outputText><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td> 
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="businessCaseAssociation">
                <c:business_shipper_contact_info theBusiness="{!businessMap[businessCaseAssociation.Business__c]}" rendered="{!businessCaseAssociation.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Importer'}"/><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="businessCaseAssociation">
                <c:business_shipper_contact_info2 theBusiness="{!businessMap[businessCaseAssociation.Business__c]}" rendered="{!businessCaseAssociation.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Importer'}"/><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="businessCaseAssociation">
                <c:business_shipper_contact_info3 theBusiness="{!businessMap[businessCaseAssociation.Business__c]}" rendered="{!businessCaseAssociation.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Importer'}"/><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>                                    
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.Incident_Locations__r}" var="loc">
                <apex:outputText value="{!loc.Port_of_Discharge__c}"></apex:outputText><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>                                    
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="bus">
                <apex:outputText value="{!bus.Business__r.Business_Name__c}" rendered="{!bus.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Notify Party'}"></apex:outputText><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td> 
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="businessCaseAssociation">
                <c:business_shipper_contact_info theBusiness="{!businessMap[businessCaseAssociation.Business__c]}" rendered="{!businessCaseAssociation.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Notify Party'}"/><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r}" var="businessCaseAssociation">
                <c:business_shipper_contact_info2 theBusiness="{!businessMap[businessCaseAssociation.Business__c]}" rendered="{!businessCaseAssociation.Business__r.Business_Type__c = 'Notify Party'}"/><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>                                                                                                
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.Products__r}" var="pro">
                <apex:outputText value="{!pro.Brand__c}"></apex:outputText>&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{!pro.Product_Types__c}"></apex:outputText>&nbsp;(<apex:outputText value="{0,number,###,###}"><apex:param value="{!pro.Total_Product_Quantity__c}"/></apex:outputText>)<br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>
            <td>
                <apex:outputText value="{!c.Total_Product__c}"></apex:outputText>
            </td>
            <td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!c.Incident_Locations__r}" var="loc">
                <apex:outputText value="{!loc.Container_Type__c}"></apex:outputText><br></br>
            </apex:repeat>
            </td>
            <td>
                <apex:outputText value="{!c.Comments_Postal_Express__c}"></apex:outputText>
            </td>            
         </tr>              
    </apex:repeat>
    </table>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```